# How to replace multiple words in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, firefox-addon

I'm searching to replace in a string many words with one another word. I'm trying to use replace method [(here the description)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) but I can't use this with multiple words. Let me use an example:

```
var test = new String("Hi how are you? lol");   
var newTest = test.replace(/lol/, "ok", "gim");
console.log(newTest);
```

This code works correctly and print "Hi how are you? ok". I wanna replace not only "lol" but also "Hi" and I'm trying to do this:

```
var test = new String("Hi how are you? lol");   
var newTest = test.replace(/lol||hi/, "ok", "gim");
console.log(newTest);
```

But the second version doesn't work. The easy solution is to insert the replace function into a for and recall the function for each word, but I would to change all words in one time. Do you have any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The regex "or" is `|`. Also note that will match "lolcat", and "hickey".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use single `|` instead of `||`. Regex supports `OR` like this only

```
var test = new String("Hi how are you? lol");   
var newTest = test.replace(/lol|Hi/gim, "ok");
console.log(newTest);
```

OUTPUT :

```
ok how are you? ok
```

also the code written is wrong. the gim modifiers will work like that only if you put like this : `.replace(new RegExp("lol|hi","gim"),"ok");`

`.replace` takes two parameters only . check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)